# ¿No es la pregunta "¿Qué función asíncrona es la óptima?" muy amplia?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

Esta pregunta:

[¿Qué función asíncrona es la óptima?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-funci%c3%b3n-as%c3%adncrona-es-la-m%c3%a1s-%c3%b3ptima)

Está formulada de forma tal que está basada en opiniones. La optimización de código depende del contexto y los requerimientos funcionales o no funcionales.

Ahora bien, la idea es interesante y por eso la votan tanto. Entonces, ¿qué hacemos con este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: Así como está para mi sí lo es, incluso la reportaría como muy amplia, **pero** las respuestas que trajo me gustaron mucho, tal ves se pueda cambiar el título a algo como ¿Qué diferencias hay entre callbacks, promises y async/await? que es en lo que se enfocaron las respuestas

Comment: Tal cual. Lo de óptimo da para que escriban un libro

Comment: @KacosPro La valoración de si una pregunta es buena o mala debería realizarse independientemente de las respuestas, una edición como la que comentas sería válida sólo si el AP ha dicho en comentarios que eso es lo que está buscando.

Comment: @Rubén Totalmente de acuerdo, por eso le puse +1 a la respuesta y me abstuve de puntuar la pregunta, de hecho si te fijas en mi comentario digo que la pregunta es muy amplia. Por otro lado yo comparto la [visión de Jeff Atwood que dice que SO es una wikipedia para programadores](https://blog.codinghorror.com/what-does-stack-overflow-want-to-be-when-it-grows-up/), así que no veo porque no podríamos editarla si se llega a un consenso.

Comment: @KacosPro No se debe cambiar el sentido que el AP le ha dado a sus pregunta, si el está de acuerdo está bien pero si no, considera publicar una pregunta nueva o espera a que alguien mas lo haga.

Comment: @Rubén nunca hablé de cambiar el sentido de la pregunta, dije que se podría cambiar el título para que se ajuste a los lineamientos, no veo razón para crear otra pregunta que me de las mismas respuestas que están ahí

Comment: Mientras la pregunta y el título sigan con el sentido que tenían inicialmente, la pregunta es muy amplia y debería ser cerrada.

Comment: Tal y como ha dicho el OP de la pregunta en numerosos casos por el chat de SOes, su intención es convertir la pregunta en wiki, y yo no le veo ningun inconveniente en que lo haga, al final es algo que va a enriquecer más la red

Comment: Como autor de la pregunta, creo que esta mal realizada pero bien respondida, mi objetivo con ella era aclararme que diferencias tenian esas tres funciones y como aplicarlas correctamente. Si creeis que es necesario darle una vuelta a la pregunta, proponed, estoy completamente abierto ya que me gustaria que acabase siendo wiki al parecerme un tema interesante

Comment: @NicolasOñate te refieres a hacerla [wiki](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/community-wiki) o que se convierta en pregunta canónica? Si es lo primero (en mi opinión) no habría porque hacerlo, tu hiciste la pregunta y atrajo buenas respuestas te mereces los puntos que esta traiga

Comment: De nuevo, como wiki, pregunta de la comunidad, contenido de etiqueta, eso era muy amplio. Si la idea era describir cada uno de esos métodos, la pregunta debía ser otra y nadie va a llegar a esas descripciones por una pregunta sobre optimización.